# recursive call with same value and reach base case

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

```
def func(num, iterble):
    if num == 0:
        return iterble
    print(num)
    func(num-1, iterble)
    
    return iterble[:-1]
print(func(10, "hi my name is slim-shady"))
```

**output: of printing num is 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1**

**desired output: 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10**

how can I recursively call `num` times but still reach base-case. with out decreasing num because I want `iterble[num-1]` always  be the same value. if I call the function `num` times with if `func(num-1, iterble)`, wont do the calls always with `num = 10`. I´ve tried to give it a variable name `n = num` and refer the base case to n, but it still the same. if their are another approach let me know.

Comment: Please update your question with the correct indentation you want. Python is very sensitive to indentation as are python programmers.

Comment: btw, notwithstanding the indentation, my guess is that ‘return iterble[num-1]’ will do what you want since your recursive function always ignores returns from lower levels.

Comment: Ok, now you’ve fixed the indentation, what does your program do? Do you want a different output to what you see?

Comment: is my output possible, or should I use another approach?

Comment: I assume you do not want to use for loop, are you allowed to add another variable in the program?

Comment: So you want `num = 10` and `num = 0` at the same time? Well guess what: that is not possible. If you want two different values for two different purposes, use two different variables.

Comment: yes, I am. I can use a for loop. but I need to run the function `num` times, but is a variable in that program that have to do the input `num` times as well. and I tought mabye a recursive call `num` times would be a good approach

Comment: @Julien but how? if I put a new variable `n = num` it still give me the same `print` even if I use `if n == 0:`

Comment: Just use a for loop. No need to over complicate with recursion here.

Comment: if I use `for _ in range(num): func(x,y)` can I run the function `num` times then? and this is a part of a much bigger code. but I need a aproach to actaully run the function `num` times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One answer is to just add another variable:

```py
def func(n, num, iterble):
    if num == 0:
        return iterble
    print(n)
    func(n, num-1, iterble)
    
    return iterble[:-1]

print(func(10, 10, "hi my name is slim-shady"))
```

Output as requested.

Comment: dude, thank you. so simple. but brain is in coma. thx agian!